# How to represent polynomials with numeric vectors in R

Tags: r, polynomial-math

In R how would one represent polynomial expressions and do polynomial math with the numeric vector objects? For example:

```
x1 <- c(2,1)  # 2 + x
x2 <- c(-1,3)  # -1 + 3*x
```

And want:

```
x1 * x2 # to return -2 + 5*x + 3*x^2
```

> **Note:** I answered a question this morning and then the poster apparently deleted it (making me wonder if it were homework.) So I am re-posting the question from memory.

Comment: Try the mpoly package?

Comment: That package does look more full-featured than 'polynom' in that it handles multivariate operations. I'm not intending to checkmark my own answer, so I invite better answers than the one I provided.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One could multiply the coefficients directly using `outer` and then aggregate the results

```
x1 <- c(2,1)  # 2 + x
x2 <- c(-1,3)  # -1 + 3*x
tmp <- outer(x1, x2)
tapply(tmp, row(tmp) + col(tmp) - 1, sum)
# 1  2  3 
#-2  5  3

x1 <- c(2, 1) # 2 + x
x2 <- c(-1, 3, 2) # -1 + 3*x + 2*x^2
tmp <- outer(x1, x2)
tapply(tmp, row(tmp) + col(tmp) - 1, sum) # should give -2 + 5*x + 7*x^2 + 2*x^3
# 1  2  3  4 
#-2  5  7  2
```

as discussed in the comments the '-1' in the code isn't necessary.  When coming up with the solution that helped me because it allowed me to map each location in the output of `outer` to where it would end up in the final vector.  If we did a '-2' instead then it would map to the exponent on x in the resulting polynomial.  But we really don't need it so something like the following would work just as well:

```
tmp <- outer(x1, x2)
tapply(tmp, row(tmp) + col(tmp), sum)
```

Comment: That's kewl. Kind of a binomial expansion triangle tilted 45 degrees counterclockwise.

Comment: This is very similar to the code in `polynom:::Ops.polynomial`, although they use `tapply(m, row(m) + col(m), sum)`... Why do both give the same result?

Comment: I actually don't need the `-1 in the code but it helped me mentally think about the problem at first.  I should probably just get rid of it.  Those numbers are just being used to group together results so we could add/subtract any amount and it would stay the same.

Comment: If you subtracted 2 instead of 1 you could use the sum as the exponent for `x`.

Comment: Yeah - I was using it as the index of the resulting vector (thus only subtracting 1 instead of 2) - but either way it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 13):

Use the polynom package:

```
 require(polynom)
# Loading required package: polynom
# From the example for as.polynomial
 p <- as.polynomial(c(1,0,3,0))
 p
# 1 + 3*x^2 

 x1 <- c(2,1)
 x2 <- c(-1,3)
 px1 <- as.polynomial(x1)
 px2 <- as.polynomial(x2)

 px1*px2
# -2 + 5*x + 3*x^2 
 prod.p <- .Last.value
 str(prod.p)
# Class 'polynomial'  num [1:3] -2 5 3
 unclass(prod.p)
# [1] -2  5  3
```

Comment: May I add that this does not allow symbolic manipulation of polynomial expressions, since the coefficients are stored as regular `double` values and precision is lost during arithmetic operations. If one needs to perform symbolic computations on such expressions, I'd suggest Mathematica instead.

Comment: There is also an Ryacas package.

Comment: If R cannot do what is wanted, I think Maxima does polynomials and is free.  Although www.wolframalpha.com is free too and I think is based on Mathematica.

Comment: R definitely can do what David asked: and the answer *is* using the polynom package, as long as you do not need exact arithmetic.

Comment: For exact (or arbitrary precise) arithmetic, I'd also like to mention the `gmp` R package (based on the GNU MP ("GMP") library), for exact integer and rational arithmetic,  *and* (my) package `Rmpfr`, based on the (GNU) MPFR library for arbitrary precision arithmetic.  What really would be neat is a marriage of 'polynom' with gmp and Rmpfr.  I'd be happy to collaborate on that.

Answer (score 2):

Polynomial multiplication is the convolution of the coefficients

```
convolve(c(2,1),rev(c(-1,3)),type="open")
#[1] -2  5  3
```