# Calculate the product of two polynomial in R

Tags: r

I want to create a function "f" which calculates the product of two polynomials

```
a0 +a1X + ···+anX^n and b0+b1X+···+bmX^m
```

For example, since (1 + x)(3 + 2x^2) = 3 + 3x + 2x^2 + 2x^3,we expect the following resuslt:

```
f(c(1,1),c(3,0,2))
  [1] 3 3 2 2
```

I have some idea here:

```
X^0: a0b0
X^1: a0b1+a1b0
X^2: a0b2+a1b1+a2b0
.
.
```

So, I have the function like this

```
A =(a0,a1,....,an),B=(b0,b1,...,bn)
f= function(A,B){
          n=length(A)
          m=length(B)
     for(k in 0:(n+m-2))
       for(j in 0:k)
             {
               C[k+1]=sum(A[j+1]*B[k-j+1])
}
     }
```

But it doesn't work when I type f(A,B)
Did anyone has better idea?

Comment: Could you give valid examples of `A` and `B`?

Comment: Yes~ I thought my function is right, but it doesn't work

Comment: use the package `polynom` .. it is already able to do the job.

Comment: Yes, input A=c(1,1),B=c(3,0,2), then output [1]3 3 2 2

Comment: You didn't create `C`. I believe that's the problem.

Comment: @J_F I think we are not allow to use the package yet.

Comment: @Hack-R What's that mean?

Comment: You're referring to an object called `C` in your function but there's no object called `C`.

Comment: It seems right, but how do I create object C ? 
 >C = matrix(col=n+m-1,row=1)  it's not work

Comment: @梁楷葳 Something like that, yes. Except it's `matrix(ncol=n+m-1,nrow=1)`. Once you've fixed that part of the problem I think there must be an additional problem we still need to fix though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16864392/1003565

Comment: The other problem is the way you've indexed the original objects. For instance `A` is of length 2 but sometimes you're trying to access the 4th element.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(polynom)
p1 <- polynomial(c(1,1))
p2 <- polynomial(c(3,0,2))

p1 * p2
#3 + 3*x + 2*x^2 + 2*x^3 

coefficients(p1 * p2)
#[1] 3 3 2 2
```

Here is how the multiplication is implemented in the package:

```
m <- outer(c(1,1), c(3,0,2))
as.vector(tapply(m, row(m) + col(m), sum))
#[1] 3 3 2 2
```

See the source code of

```
polynom:::`Ops.polynomial`
```

Comment: thank you, but we are not allow to use 'polynom' yet

Comment: SO is not a homework service. This is a valid answer to your question. You are under no obligation to accept it, but I prefer to provide this answer for others.

Comment: @梁楷葳 If you want to ask a homework question on SO they ask that you show some effort (which you did), label it as being for homework, and cite SO in your assignment. So basically you just need to label it as being for homework.

Comment: Yes, I have no issue with your question. But you are asking for better ideas and this is better. Outside of homework, if you had valid reasons not to use a package, you could just extract the code from package polynom.

Comment: @梁楷葳 Yes, you did. I was just saying that you also need to label it as homework. This gives people context so that they provide relevant answers, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer